# Drawing circles to canvas using functions

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

```
    <div>

        <canvas id="canvas" width="250px" height="400px" style="border: 1px solid black" onload="drawCircle()"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
var canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

function drawCircle(){

    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50,50,50,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Just wondering if anyone can tell me why this does not draw to canvas. If I remove the code from the function it works.

Comment: You call the function from an `onload` event attribute on your canvas element, but I don't think canvas elements have an `onload` event. (Why would they? What is there for them to load?) Call the function from within your script instead.

Comment: you are not calling the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not invoke your function.
please append this code below your codes;

```
drawCircle();
```